# How can I identify a video resolution with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, resolution

Once a video is uploaded to a html file input field, how could I identify the video resolution with javascript? 360p, 720p, 1080p, or 4K.

Comment: Since 360p, 720p etc are just numbers of horizontal lines, you probably want to look at [videoHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoHeight#about_intrinsic_width_and_height) property of your `video` element.

Comment: @Kosh that only accesses the video frames height not the video files resolution. How can I get the resolution not dimensions of the video frame.

Comment: Please determine resolution how you understand it. For me, for example, 720p is 1280×720 pixels.

Comment: @Kosh I understand resolution to be the quality of the video. The higher the quality the less blur. For example youtube 320p vs 720p. 320p is blurry quality while 720p is high HD quality.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand it. Video (same as picture) looks blurry if its size (resolution) is smaller than the size of the container where the video is displayed. So browser has to stretch the video extrapolating its data. So if offset width and height of the video were equal or less than `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` you'd got crispy clear "quality". Unfortunately comments on StackOverflow is not the best place for long explanations, but hope it helps. RTFM in the first comment, you may want to dig it a bit.